# Class not found in Tomcat instance, even though every possible artifact that includes it was included as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey

```
SEVERE: Servlet [com.mycompany.mycms.screport.services.CmsPortfolioConfig] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager$PrivilegedLoadClass.run(DefaultInstanceManager.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager$PrivilegedLoadClass.run(DefaultInstanceManager.java:823)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

I have a Tomcat application that mostly provides RESTful api services via Jersey's JAX-RS implementation.  At the some point in startup it decides to throw the above class not found exception. Initially, I started with these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it did not care, and gave me the same stack trace. So I gave up and in desperation tried all of the remaining:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I did the build, and asked Eclipse to publish the changes to the Tomcat instance (v9). But I got the above stack trace.  I tried adding this dependency, because search.maven.org reports that it provides the missing class.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.31</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-helidon-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-wadl-doclet</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>custom-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.examples</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And it *still* did not care.  I *thought* it was complaining because it could not find the class.  I can appreciate that if I did not provide it.  However, I thought the fc: qualifier in the maven search tools allows me to find the artifact that provides the class.  Somehow, this is all incorrect.

Incidentally, I can press Ctrl-Shift-T, type in the fully qualified type and see it in Eclipse, even the source.  I have no idea why it cannot find that class.

Separately, my services all return 404 from Tomcat.  I wonder if it is because of this error or something else.

https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer%20v:2.31

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, please check your Deployment Assembly in the project. You can do this in eclipse by right-clicking the project and going to properties. Has everything been deployed there? Maybe you have all classes in the source file but it has not been deployed.